# Holomorphic function on the open unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Question: Let f be a holomorphic function on the unit disc $\{|z|<1\}$, which of the following is/are necessarily true?

1. If for each positive integer n we have $f(1/n)=1/n^2$ then $f(z)=z^2$ on the unit disc.
2. If for each positive integer n we have $f(1-1/n)=(1-1/n)^2$ then $f(z)=z^2$ on the unit disc.
3. f cannot satisfy $f(1/n)=(-1)^n/n$ for each positive integer n.
4. f cannot satisfy $f(1/n)=1/(n+1)$ for each positive integer n.

I have an intuitive feeling that (1) and (4) are true, but that's not helping!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Statements 1 and 3 are true, but Statements 2 and 4 are false.

Statement 1 follows from the identity theorem for holomorphic functions. For the conditions imply that $f(z)$ agrees with $z^2$ on the infinite set $\{1/n : n\in \Bbb N\}$, which has $0$ as an accumulation point in the disc. So $f(z) = z^2$ for all $z$ in the disc.

For Statement 2, consider the function $f(z) = z^2 e^{2\pi i/(1 - z)}$ is holomorphic in the open unit disc and satisifies $f(1 - 1/n) = (1 - 1/n)^2 e^{2\pi i n} = (1 - 1/n)^2$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$, but $f(z)\neq z^2$ for all $z$ in the disc. Therefore, Statement 2 is false.

To see why Statement 3 is true, note that if $f$ satisfies the hypotheses, then $f(z)$ agrees with $g(z) := z$ on the infinite set $\{\frac{1}{2n} : n\in \Bbb N\}$, which has $0$ as a point of accumulation lying in the disc.  So $f \equiv g$ by the identity theorem. However, $f(1) = -1 \neq 1 = g(1)$.

Since $f(z) = z/(z + 1)$ is holomorphic in the open unit disc and satisfies $f(1/n) = 1/(n + 1)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$, Statement 4 is false.

Comment: It requires that $\{1/n : n\in \Bbb N\}$ is an infinite subset of the unit disc having a point of accumulation -- which is true.

Comment: should the point of accumulation be in the considered region?

Comment: And yes, just cross checked with the question, it is open unit disc.Can you make the necessary correction in your answer? I will correct the question too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've made the necessary changes. Hope it's all clear now. :)