# All entire function with $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

As you can see in the title I need help with the following exercise:

Find all entire function with $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^2}$
I guess I have to use the identity theorem but I dont know how

Comment: Hint: let $g(x)=x^2$. Then $f(1/n)=g(1/n)$, presumably for all $n$.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213088/42969.

Answer (score 1):

$f(z):=z^2$  will do the job. If $g$ is an entire function with the same property and $h:=f-g$, then $h(1/n)=0$ for all $n$, hence, by the identity theorem: $f=g$ on $ \mathbb C.$